# How to rename field name in Elasticsearch with Time efficient?

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, time

I have been using the following query to rename fieldName.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_update_by_query
{
    "query": { 
        "exists": {
            "field": "NEW_FIELD_NAME"
        }
    },
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.NEW_FIELD_NAME = ctx._source.OLD_FIELD_NAME; ctx._source.remove(\"OLD_FIELD_NAME\");"
    }
}
```

But for more than 4.2 million data. It takes about 2-3 minutes.

Is there any way to reduce the duration?

The ElasticSearch version is `5.6.4`

Comment: Got reply [discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-rename-field-name-in-elasticsearch-with-time-efficient/299179)

Answer (score 0):

David's answer on Discuss is the hard way. If you're looking for an easy way, and if your index has more than 1 primary shard, you can use [slicing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-automatic-slice) in order to parallelize the work:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_update_by_query?slices=auto&wait_for_completion=false
{
    ...
}
```

But David is right, you should upgrade at some point ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A totally different way to do this which ensures zero downtime is to first create a new index map with the updated field name.

After that, you can use the reindex API to populate data to this new index.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Assuming you are using aliases, you can update the underlying index for this alias once re-indexing is finished.
This will assure there is no downtime in the application using this data. Reindex API also supports various conf params to make the indexing process faster.

Comment: There's no downtime with the update_by_query approach, either